# php include with ".." before file path

Tags: php, include-path

I recently was watching a php video tutorial and the author was showing how to do include a file. He was using XAMPP for the demonstrations and had many files.

When he was showing how to include a file, he mentioned something about putting two dots (..) in front of the file path (/xampp/content/example.html) because of something having to do with where the files were located, assuming that I already had knowledge of this principle. But i don't.

Can anyone explain what is up with having one dot or two dots in front of file paths?

What is the difference between `include("/xampp/content/example.html");`, `include("./xampp/content/example.html");`, and `include("../xampp/content/example.html");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Linux / Unix environment,

`/xampp/content/example.html` means absolute path

`./xampp/content/example.html` means relative path of current directory

`../xampp/content/example.html` means relative path of parent directory

For the folder structure: `/var/www/xampp/content/example3.html`:

If your current folder is `/var/www/`...

- `../` (goes up 1 level) will be `/var/`
- `./` (in current level) will be `/var/www/`
- `/` will be `/` (in Linux, `/` means the root of the server, the outermost structure of the filesystem)
- `../../` (goes up 2 level) will be `/`

There are 2 types of paths: **Relative Path** & **Absolute Path**.

For Relative path, it's relative to your current directory. For absolute path, it's not related to your current directory.

Comment: Is this still the case today? I'm including a PHP file which is two levels up, with just `../` and yet it finds the file. If I put `../../` which would make sense to use, it can't find the file.

Comment: @user2924019 depends on the permission.

Answer (score 1):

`.` means the same directory as the script that's doing the including, `..` means the parent directory of the one containing the script. So `../xampp/content/example.html` means to go up one folder level from the current script, then go into its `xampp/content` subdirectory to find `example.html`.

A path beginning with `/` is an absolute path from the root of the server. Using absolute paths makes it harder to move your project to a new directory, because you'll need to update all the paths. Relative paths allow you to move everything as a group without changing the paths, because the directory relationships will stay the same.